dependency problems when Install Cisco Packet Tracer 822 on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS (Noble Numbat)
I got an Error Message when Install Cisco Packer  Tracer 822 on Ubuntu. This the command I run on Terminal :
sudo dpkg -i Packet_Tracer822_amd64_signed.deb
[sudo] password for abdan-syakuran: 
Selecting previously unselected package packettracer.
(Reading database ... 148068 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack Packet_Tracer822_amd64_signed.deb ...
Unpacking packettracer (8.2.2) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of packettracer:
 packettracer depends on dialog; however:
  Package dialog is not installed.
 packettracer depends on libgl1-mesa-glx; however:
  Package libgl1-mesa-glx is not installed.
 packettracer depends on libxcb-xinerama0-dev; however:
  Package libxcb-xinerama0-dev is not installed.


See https://community.cisco.com/t5/cisco-software-discussions/unable-to-install-packet-tracer-on-ubuntu-24-04-lts/td-p/5079326 which gives steps to install the package. (Posting as comment because I cannot test it myself)

dpkg does not solve dependencies, apt does so use apt ;) @karel was slighty quicker than me :(

Thank you very much!

Open the terminal, change directories with cd to the directory containing Packet_Tracer822_amd64_signed.deb, and run the following command:
sudo apt install ./Packet_Tracer822_amd64_signed.deb

This command will install Packer Tracer 822 on Ubuntu 24.04 together with its dependencies.
